# i want to create a keywordName search api to get data from aws

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i want to create keywordsearch api were when i call api by passing in body  keywordName like i phone i want the impression click,acos,cpc etc.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: 'AKIAIOSFODNN7',
  secretAccessKey: 'wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCY',
  region: 'us-east-1',
});
const pinpoint = new AWS.Pinpoint();

app.post('/keyword', (req, res) => {
  const keywordName = req.body.keywordName;

  const params = {
    Filters: [
      {
        Name: 'Keyword',
        Value: keywordName,
      },
    ],
  };

  pinpoint.listKeywordFilters(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error retrieving KeywordFilterName:', err);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to retrieve data' });
    } else {
      if (data.KeywordFilters.length === 0) {
        res.status(404).json({ error: 'Keyword not found' });
      } else {
        const keywordDetails = data.KeywordFilters[0];
        res.json(keywordDetails);
      }
    }
  });
});`
```